# How are we to understand the earth does not move?

Tags: contradiction, psalms, job, ecclesiastes

How are we to understand the creation of the earth / world and does the bible contradict science. A few passages;

> Psalm 104:5 - He set the earth on its ***foundations;*** it can ***never be moved.*** (NIV)

> Ecclesiastes 1:5 - The sun rises and the sun sets, and ***hurries back to where it rises.*** (NIV)

> Job 9:6 He shakes the earth from its place and makes its ***pillars tremble.*** (NIV)

- Earth moves and the other planets rotate and move in space around the Sun.
- Earth cannot have pillars otherwise it opposes axis of rotation.

Comment: It doesnt contradict science bec it is an ancient literature, it does not make scientific claims.

Comment: @Michael16 'ancient literature' - is the bible not Gods word / inspired / earth created by God etc... ?

Comment: Earth is created by God, but the bible is completely written by man for man. If the reality appears contrary to the literature, you should change your interpretation of it rather than denying the reality of the world. "We must be on our guard against giving interpretations which are hazardous or opposed to science, and so exposing the word of God to the ridicule of unbelievers- Augustin (De Genesi ad litteram, I, 19, 21, especially n. 39)" https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94966/did-st-augustine-warn-us-about-interpreting-the-bible-in-a-way-which-harms-scie/94977#94977

Comment: @Michael16 - the way I read your comment, you seem to be contradicting yourself - if the bible is from man (not Gods word or inspired by God) - you cannot expose God as the bible is not Gods word.  Your exposing the bible and those who wrote the bible.  So, your answer would be that the bible is not Gods word and therefore the author was wrong, I presume (as God cannot be wrong)!

Comment: The "Word of God" belief comes from the virtue of the fact that the authors were men of God, thus, we call their writings' word of God, it is quite figurative.

Comment: @Michael16 - 'men of God' would imply inspired / guided by God - So are they wrong?

Comment: They can be wrong on minor things like this when you judge them on a totally wrong and modern scientific perspective, something which mocks literature. They are not wrong, the hermeneutical approach is wrong and misguided.

Comment: Any point in the universe may be taken as the 'centre' and all things then take their place in regard to it. God chose to make the earth the centre.

Comment: These kinds of questions are obtuse. Enough so that I think it's usually intentional. I'm certainly not interested in a puerile Gish gallop.

Comment: So many like to say things such as the Bible is not a book of science.  That is a bad way to counter these questions.  Whenever God speaks about any subject it is the absolute truth!  God says the earth does not move.  Mainstream science who deny God's existence says it spins on an axis and travels around the sun, which concept when examined at the stated heliocentric endorsed model finds that the speed of the earth's rotation would never catch up enough to the speed of the sun's movement through the universe to be able to move in front of it.  I'll stick with God's word.

Answer (score 3):

Not so fast - even today we say the "sun rises" despite the fact everyone knows that it is the earth's rotation that makes the sun appear to rise.  We also talk about the rotation of the heavens/stars which is actually caused by the earth's rotation and precession of the earth's orbit, etc.

The language of Ps 104 (and other places) is highly poetic, for example:

- V3a - laying the beams of His chambers in the waters above
- V3b - making the clouds His chariot, walking on the wings of the wind
- V4 - He makes the winds His messengers, flames of fire His servants.
- V28 - When You give it [food] to them [creatures], they gather it up; when You open Your hand, they are satisfied with good things.

None of these things is literally true - the creatures of the earth do not literally fed from God's hand; God's throne is not literally in the rain-bearing clouds; God does not literally ride in a chariot made of clouds, etc.

Lastly, the comment in V5 about the earth not moving cannot also be taken to be literally true for several reasons:

1. the language is poetic as described above
2. the ancients were familiar with earthquakes just as we are today
3. In the same Ps 104:32, we see a description of the earth "trembling" when God looks at the earth.  Again, this describes (if taken literally) the moving of the earth which, should, again, be taken poetically and metaphorically.
4. It is not a scientific statement and does not try to be.  We should never judge ancient literature by modern ways of thinking.

**CONCLUSION**

Ps 104 is a wonderful celebration and rehearsal of the greatness, majesty, wisdom and omnipotence of God and the world He created for us.  Let us allow the Hebrew poets some literary license.

Ellicott sums this up well when he writes:

> (5) Who laid . . .—Better, He fixed the earth on its foundations.
> (Comp. Job 38:4-6; Proverbs 8:29.)
>
> The inconsistency of this with Job 26:7, “He laid the earth upon
> nothing,” need not cause difficulty. Both treatments are poetical, not
> scientific. The word foundations implies stability and endurance
> (comp. Psalm 82:5), as in Shakespeare’s
>
> “The frame and huge foundation of the earth.”

Benson is similar:

> Psalm 104:5. Who laid the foundations of the earth — Hebrew, יסד ארצ
> על מכוניה, jasad eretz gnal mechoneah, who hath founded the earth upon
> its own bases, or foundations, that is, upon itself, or its own centre
> of gravity, by which it is self-balanced, and by which it stands as
> fast and immoveable as if it were built upon the strongest foundation
> imaginable, which is a most stupendous work of divine wisdom and
> power; that it should not be removed — Out of its proper place; for
> ever — Or, till the end of time, when it must give way to the new
> earth.

Comment: I guess we'll have to discard all of modern science because there are scientists who have used the word "sunrise" or poetry. Tis a shame....

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - quite true - human language is far more poetic than many realize.

Comment: I’m surprised that modern science somehow is allowed to define Scripture. So science is the standard and superior to the Bible? You wrote *”We should never judge ancient literature by modern ways of thinking.”* and yet you have done precisely that, when you discarded the whole ancient cosmology as fake and hyperbolic, BECAUSE you judged ancient literature by modern ways of thinking. That is a perfect example of forcing modern cosmology onto the text, you’ve dismissed the whole writings as uninspired and scientifically inaccurate. No one in ancient times would agree with your modern assessment

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - I am not allowing science to define Scripture.  All I said was that we cannot take this passage literally for the reasons stated - there are many other statements here that are clearly metaphorical and poetic such as God riding on a chariot of clouds and placing beams etc.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo & others - the point seems to be only 'God' could have given this knowledge as clearly at the time men did not have this knowledge.  If the scriptures are a true guide they would complement science not contradict.   To imply as @ Michael16 that men of 'God' make minor errors would raise issues about the bible, not science.

Comment: @another you just made my point, and besides it isn’t that men describe the earth this way in the Bible, God Himself does too, now the dilemma went from men being ignorant to God being deceptive and fee forcing a lie.

Comment: @Dottard when you said “all I said was that we cannot take this passage literally for reasons stated” you have exactly allowed science to trump the Bible but the text was written for the ancients and it was LITERALLY true the cosmology they believed. And here you come along and dismiss their cosmology which they accepted as true on the basis of SCIENCE. Which makes science the superior revelation and forces you to claim the scriptures are metaphors and poetry. That’s precisely what I accused you of and you just restated in your comment above as why science is not superior

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - 1) God being deceptive - NO 2) 'cosmology they believed' - the bible was inspired (or supposed to be) irrelevant of what they knew at the time, God created and knows everything - ***its not about science*** then & now, that's a distraction - its about, is the bible correct and if not - it cannot be Gods word or inspired.  The prophets were all inspired (guided by God) - so  this is by others that would be the obvious conclusion.

Comment: @another you’re making my point again. Now go ahead and admit that you either trust God who describes the earth as having a firmament, local heavenly bodies, is a plain with upturned edges holding in the ocean and is fixed on pillars such that it does not move, spin, displace or travel in an way or deny the Claims made by God and reject everything He says. It’s really that simple. Go ahead tell us which one is your choice, we can deduce it from your first point but say it more plainly.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo im not making your point at all on any of my comments - I trust God - but if the Bible is contradictory to science then the Bible is wrong and cannot be God's word or inspired.  God cannot ever be wrong.  If Gods word or guidance then it would have been accurate to what we know now.  God is not limited to knowledge men are.   I thought I was quite clear in my comments - nothing to deduce.  You don't seem to be very clear - Do you say that this is Gods word even though it contradicts the knowledge we have now?

Comment: @another so when God says and is being quoted word for word and not a prophet speaking on behalf of God what the earth is like, you’re saying that since those words contradict the science, then those words are wrong. But that God is still trustworthy. Even though He would then therefore be incapable of communicating accurately the truth anywhere in any form for people to know what He claims. Got it, so you just put the Bible in the trash but still hold onto God as trustworthy without any literary revelation. And science trumps the Scriptures that how we know the scriptures are wrong. Got it

Comment: @Dottard and just to make it more clear to you, the Scriptures were written to the ancient audience, none of which believed or even knew about a future modern secular cosmology. When they read/heard the text they didn’t think, oh this is not literal, they, the people for whom the Scriptures were written understood it literally. You have no hermeneutic or exegetic license to impose non literal based on a future secular claimed cosmology. The text must be understood literally as it was intended for the original audience. Whether you reject their cosmology or not, your view is moot and irrelevant

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - you seem to be making my comments more complicated then they are - simple if it contradicts science then it cannot be Gods word & yes the bible or who wrote that part is wrong.   There's numerous issues with the bible and if you don't accept that your only kidding yourself.

Comment: @another that what I said, science trumps the Bible making the Bible uninspired because science is the superior revelation/arbitra of truth according to you. (This also rejects God as competent but alas)

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - well if its wrong it cannot be inspired or Gods word.  ***God is always right*** or do you say the bible is the word of God or inspired even though it is wrong or contradictory?

Comment: Re lengthy discussion above, if the Bible were perfectly in harmony with the science of today, it would be out of harmony with the science of tomorrow. Perhaps then it's a good thing that God used symbols rather than equations to reveal truth, and thus didn't reveal more information/detail than people were prepared to receive.

Comment: @another I’m saying the science is fabricated and wrong. And you’re deceived and willing to besmirch God’s word on the basis of fake claims. The Bible is not wrong in its cosmology. The earth is exactly as the Bible says but you’re too indoctrinated to know it. And have given credibility to liars.

Comment: @hold the Bible doesn’t need to be in line with science of today which as you point out is ever changing anyway. But you too are thoroughly indoctrinated into modern secular cosmology that you can’t even begin to understand why the whole moderns secular cosmology is actually a lie and a fabrication. However you are NOT entitled to diminish the Bible’s cosmology to symbolism just to give credit to your religious creed in modern secular cosmology and account for your cognitive dissonance that is trying to marry two incompatible cosmologies. You have to define it as the ancient readers read it

Comment: @NihilSineDeo so when the bible implies in a number of passages that the earth is flat and science has proved (not theory) its round (oval, egg shaped etc...), we should still believe its flat?  And I reiterate I'm not saying God is wrong, the people who wrote the bible are, as its clearly not Gods word or inspired.

Comment: @another science has not proven it’s a sphere, but I have no intention of proving something that is so obviously a lie, to indoctrinated uninterested minds, when you take the words of military operatives that had and have an agenda (NASA) and have hoaxed and made up all their “facts”. No one has gone to the moon, we have never left lower earth orbit, CGI is not proof, fisheye lenses are not proof, the same stars in the night sky all year round is not proof we are orbiting. I would recommend a free resource by a globe believer called The Principle by Robert Sungenis, at least watch the trailer.

Answer (score 1):

Biblical cosmology is entirely incompatible with modern secular cosmology. Anyone attempting to force the Biblical text into modern secular cosmology is not approaching hermeneutics and exegesis honestly.

The text was written for the ancient reader, with the ancient reader in mind.

As such the earth in Biblical cosmology is a plane, has two heavens, one up to the clouds, one between the top of the clouds and the firmament and then the third heaven above it. The underworld and Sheol is under the earth’s plane, it is fixed on pillars and it does not move. The ends of the earth are upturned to hold in the ocean (the ancients didn’t divide the one water into many oceans like we have name different regions today) and the sun, moon and stars are local.

Here is a graphic from the prestigious resource Logos Bible Software diagraming what the ancients envisioned the universe looked like.

[image]

As such there are no planets as defined by modern secular cosmology, only as they were described even by the ancient Greeks, wandering stars. Joshua literally told the sun and moon to stop because the earth was not moving in the first place.

When the text in Hebrew says the earth does not move, it doesn’t move, it doesn’t displace itself, it’s not spinning, it’s not turning, it is fixed. Earthquakes are localized and it is not the whole earth that is moving, as such it does not contradict the statement that the earth does not move. It is fixed on pillars.

A great resource is Michael S Heiser who although subscribed to modern secular cosmology had enough scholarly integrity to let the text say what it said and did not try to force the text to fit into the modern secular paradigm.

If Biblical cosmology is understood as the ancients understood it, then the passages agree with each other, otherwise it’s hard to make sense of certain phenomena like Joshua telling the sun and moon to stop or Peter saying that the firmament will be rolled up like a scroll, or the stars will fall to the earth.

Comment: Images like that always seem far more detailed than what I actually see in the scriptures. No doubt that it was a Jewish cosmology at some point, but I don't think we can say with certainty that the authors of the Psalms had that exact model.

Comment: It’s sourced @curiousdannii from Logos Bible Software, by very competent scholars, I could start to list the verses myself but if you haven’t dedicated yourself to studying this subject in exclusivity, it wouldn’t matter because you’re not an authority on the subject as it stands. There are over 200 verses that contribute to the creation of this diagram and the major items are depicted. Besides it corroborates with numerous archaeological depictions from multiple civilizations in antiquity. The burden would be on you to prove otherwise based on the preponderance of verses and artifacts

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - you could help your cause if you could point to the place when the edge of the earth exists.  If you point me to such a place, I would be convinced.  In the mean-time, I believe my experienced of having flown around the entire globe.

Comment: @Dottard the information is publicly available and you won’t look into it anyway even if I showed you where. The Antarctica treaty Article VI prevents anyone from passing past 60o south latitude. All unauthorized attempts have either been turned back or destroyed/killed. Only authorized visits at certain allowed bases. According to the non-sanitized original records of Captain Cook & James Clark Ross circumnavigated Antarctica taking 3-4 years and between 50,000-60,000 miles around. British ship Challenger made an indirect but complete circumnavigation of Antarctica traversing 69,000 miles

Comment: Also you have only ever flown around latitudinally (if indeed you did it in one continuous circumnavigation). That is indeed possible on the Bible earth, look at the United Nations emblem pick an equatorial country and follow the equator around on that flat earth emblem. Possible. Never have you flown longitudinally passing over and beyond the South Pole, that is something you have NEVER done. You reject the Scriptures on account of a secular cosmology and justify saying it’s not literal but metaphor or poetic BASED on the secular cosmology of today. Just be honest, you deny Scripture is true.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - Actually, I have flown over the south pole -it was most interesting.

Comment: @Dottard I’m sure you have G

Answer (score 1):

**Background**
How are we to understand passages in the Bible which seem to contradict science? This is an excellent question. When addressing this issue there are two things to keep in mind.

First, science is often wrong. This especially true for new discoveries which are almost always misunderstood to some degree. But to the point of this question, all new discoveries mean what was previously taught was wrong. An obvious example is the Big Bang, which replaced the Newtonian model of the universe. After teaching a false theory of cosmology for over 300 years, science celebrated the Big Bang Theory. Yet history does not criticize science for over 300 years of teaching something which is now declared to be wrong.

To illustrate this issue by way of example, consider recall notices automobile makers send out. The principle is simple: the car is unsafe or fails to properly perform and the manufacturer has an obligation to correct the flaw. Do colleges recall degrees for teaching something which is discovered to be incorrect? Do professors reach out to former students to advise them they were given wrong information? When textbooks are rewritten with correct information, are previous students given replacements at no cost?

In some cases, like the cosmology of the Newtonian model, science was known to be wrong.<sup>`1`</sup>Further, science was not simply wrong by providing an inaccurate natural explanation; the error was compounded by claiming the Biblical account was inaccurate. Not only were there no recalls or replacement books: there was no *mea culpa*. When Nobel Prizes are given there is never an accompanying apology or retraction for wrongly claiming the Biblical account was in error.

Second, scientific accuracy, or lack there of, should be determined from the original language, not translations. I am quite certain that had science not misinformed the King James translators by teaching the Newtonian model of cosmology, many passages would have been translated differently. In which case the accuracy of Biblical cosmology should cause all readers to ask: how did scientifically illiterate writers get it right long before science understood the physics which prove it is right? Sadly, the first translations into English were negatively influenced by ill-informed science.

**Psalm 104:5**
Arguably, some things are common knowledge and scientific accuracy is expected:

> He set the earth on its foundations; it can never be moved. (Psalm 104:5 NIV)

As some answers discuss, the "inaccuracy" can be dismissed on the grounds or poetic language or the use of a metaphor or figure of speech. After all, something written to describe something else using figures of speech should not be judged as inaccurate because the figures of speech are not literally correct.

On the other hand, if the original statement, including the figure of speech, is from God, can't we also expect scientifically accuracy? When a translator approaches a text, what is their translation philosophy? Scientific accuracy is not likely to be at the top of the list, nor should it be. That is, a translator should not render a passage in a way which compromises the most important sense in order to produce a rendering which satisfies science.

However, when one chooses to throw down the gauntlet and claim the Bible lacks scientific accuracy, then it is fair to respond to such claims by re-examining the passage with scientific accuracy in mind.

> יסד־ארץ על־מכוניה בל־תמוט עולם ועד (Psalm 104:5)
> laid the earth upon the foundations of so not  it should be moved forever and ever

What are the *foundations*? The word in question is מָכוֹן which is typically understood as *place* and more precisely, as a *dwelling place*:

> I have indeed built you an exalted house, a place for you to **dwell** in forever.” (1 Kings 8:13)

When dedicating the Temple, Solomon uses מָכוֹן four times ([8:13, 39, 43, and 49](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%208%3A13%2C%2039%2C%2043%2C%2049&version=ESV)). The meaning is obvious: the Temple will be a dwelling place for the LORD.

As we think of the earth's *dwelling place* in the solar system, we must admit a proper description should be written as plural. Since the earth orbits the sun, a singular dwelling would be scientifically inaccurate. The earth's position relative to the sun is one of both motion **and** stability. The earth is in motion but it does not move about randomly. The phase is scientifically accurate if one chooses to understand it is speaking of an **unmovable dwelling place**, not a dwelling place which does not move.

In addition, the word *move* is מוֹט. The first time this is used in Leviticus:

> “If your brother becomes poor and cannot maintain himself with you, you shall support him as though he were a stranger and a sojourner, and he shall live with you. (Leviticus 25:35)
> וכי־ימוך אחיך ומטה ידו עמך והחזקת בו גר ותושב וחי עמך

In Leviticus, וּמָ֥טָה challenges translators. How is one to understand a brother's "lack of movement?" *Falls into poverty* or *cannot maintain himself* work, but with the earth's orbit in mind one might better understand the sense is to *fall out of place* or *move away*. In the same way the earth will not leave it's orbit, a poor brother is to be supported so they do not have to move away.

One may also consider the accuracy of the first word יסד which is understood as *laid*.

> He laid the earth in its dwelling places [its orbit] which will never be moved.

Is there any scientific theory which predicts the earth leaving its orbit and moving to a different place in the solar system or even another system?

Actually, the phrase *He laid...* follows Genesis 1 in which the earth is created before the sun, and the moon, and the stars. Isn't that good for a laugh! But what does science teach about the formation of the earth? Since only hydrogen and helium came from the Big Bang all other elements must have originated in stars. When these stars exploded, all other elements were strewn throughout the universe. In other words, the stars which **now** give light to the earth could not be the stars which gave the elements which make up the earth, according to scientific theory.

The Biblical sequence is declared absurdly wrong, but the scientific theory which is deemed correct "borrows" the sequence of the formation of matter from the Bible.

Science now teaches the moon was formed after a collision between a Mars sized object and the earth. Here is something to consider. What if science decides it was not the object traveling through space which collided with the earth; it was the earth which was traveling through the solar system when it collided with the object. As a result of the collision, the earth is then found in a fixed position. *When He **laid** the earth in its dwelling places*. There is a Nobel Prize just waiting for the next person to prove the Bible's scientific accuracy. Let's pray the winner stops the plagiarism and gives credit to where the idea was first written.

**Ecclesiastes 1:5**

> The sun rises and the sun sets, and hurries back to where it rises.

If ever one should show a little grace, this passage is the poster child. After all, the passage is not only poetic, it personifies the sun. No one supposes the writer understood the sun as a person. Do we criticize Shakespeare or Longfellow for taking poetic license in describing nature?

But let's take up the gauntlet science may throw down:

> וזרח השמש ובא השמש ואל־מקומו שואף זורח הוא שם
> and rises the sun and goes down the sun, and to the place hastens arose it where

First, since the terms "sunrise" and "sunset" are still in use and mean the same now as then, science has no right to declare the first part of the passage is inaccurate. *And rise the sun and goes the down sun* is describing natural events as they are experienced by mankind. The same terminology continues to this day. The weather report will detail the time of sunrise and sunset.

Of course the sun does not move, it stays in one place, an idea which can be found in what follows: ואל־מקומו is understood as *and to the place*. However, if we dig deeper into the meaning we could understand the phrase as *and against the standing in place* since אל can mean against and מקומו can describe a standing place.

The next two words are verbs שואף זורח, literally *hastening arose*. But the most common meaning of שואף is *to swallow up*. So we could see the passage as expressing two separate ideas, the first a common figure of speech and the second a scientifically accurate statement of what takes place:

> (A) the sun rise and the sun goes down
> (B) against the standing in place it swallows up the place which it rose

**Job 9:6**
First, I would point out anyone who experienced the loss of ten children, destruction of most of their worldly possessions, and a horrific and painful skin disease, should be not critiqued for scientifically accuracy.

Second, what is recorded is what **Job believes**. If one sees scientific inaccuracies in Job's understanding of the physical world, how is that any different from Isaac Newton's wrong understanding of the universe? Science is never critiqued for teaching "facts" which are not. Why must a grieving man's wrong understanding of the universe be taken as a **Biblical** inaccuracy? Can't we put this in the same category as others incorrect knowledge of nature?

If one chooses to set aside the grace extended to Newton and all scientists who have ever been wrong, we can examine what Job says with the heartless objectivity of science:

> המרגיז ארץ ממקומה ועמודיה יתפלצון
> literal: he shakes earth out of its place and its pillars tremble

First, ארץ is just earth, not **the** earth, and so it can mean land, country, even just the soil. Second, *pillars* need not be solid or even immovable columns. The most frequent use is to describe the supernatural physical manifestations of the LORD which guided the Israelites from Egypt:

> And the LORD went before them by day in a pillar of cloud to lead them along the way, and by night in a pillar of fire to give them light, that they might travel by day and by night. (Exodus 13:21)

The word which is translated as *trembles* is פָּלַץ, a hapax legomenon. It could mean *tremble* but it is fair to say Job did not use the common word for shake or tremble. Rather he has a different type of "tremble" in mind. Perhaps Job is describing God in terms of an earthquake, or a volcanic eruption, or the one responsible for the rise and fall of earthly empires. The actual language could be coerced into any of these interpretations.

But what exactly is Job saying? Is he, like Isaac Newton ignorant of correct cosmology? Is he just "running his mouth" without understanding what he is saying?

> ...Therefore I have uttered what I did not understand, things too wonderful for me, which I did not know. (Job 42:3)

Regardless of any scientific inaccuracy, at least Job had sense enough to admit he uttered things which he did not understand. Can the same be said of Isaac Newton?

---

<sub>1. The orbit of Mercury was known to violate Newton's laws of motion.</sub>

Comment: When it brings pillars into the discussion we are no longer invoking a local plot of land, it’s clearly speaking about THE earth. It doesn’t have to say the earth like in English for a Hebrew to understand it’s the earth. Interesting dissonance. Also note that neither the Hebrew nor the Greek only the translations say the sun rises and sets, the words are comes and goes. This because in Biblical cosmology they are rotating locally over a non rotating flat terrain.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Perhaps. I think the hapax legomenon calls into question the idea pillars are meant to taken as most intend. And the missing article does permit other interpretations. I am not necessarily saying that is the meaning. I am saying, 1) the sun rising and the sun going down are still contemporary vernacular which are not evaluated for literal scientific accuracy. 2) Other meanings are possible, even if it is unlikely. 3) No one uses this standard when evaluating scientists - example, Isaac Newton is known for what he got right, not his colossal error.

Answer (score 1):

The Greek Septuagint (LXX) translated Psalm 105:5 a couple of hundred years BCE as follows: “The one laying the foundation of the earth in its stability--it shall not lean into the eon of the eon.”

The translated Hebrew word is “mot,” which means to totter like a building, shake, or slip like a foot. Its negation doesn’t mean immobile.

Notice that Psalm 105:2 was also contrary to science and ridiculous until science decided that the observed redshift was almost entirely due to the expansion of space-time rather than from a static, infinite universe:
[Mystery of the Universe’s Expansion Rate Widens With New Hubble Data](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2019/mystery-of-the-universe-s-expansion-rate-widens-with-new-hubble-data)

According to Genesis 1, the earth was originally covered by water, which is contrary to science and ridiculous . . . except for
[Earth may have been a water world 3 billion years ago](https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2021/04/harvard-scientists-determine-early-earth-may-have-been-a-water-world/)

And Genesis asserts that this water was older than the sun, which is also ridiculous and contrary to science . . . except for
[Earth's Water Is Older Than the Sun](https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/earths-water-is-older-than-the-sun)

Genesis indicates that light preceded the formation of that sun and other stars, which is contrary to science and ridiculous, except for this chronology where the stars formed *after* light came into existence . . .
[History of the Universe](https://universe.nasa.gov/resources/251/history-of-the-universe/)

Ancient cosmologies often describe warring gods, dismemberment, and repurposed body parts in their creation stories. The earth is supported on the backs of large animals such as tortoises and elephants. One of the Greek Titans, Atlas, holds up the heavens. The sun and moon are powerful deities.  In contrast, the Bible contains no similar stories.

But, according to the “stone-age goat-herders” who wrote Genesis, the sun and moon are simply luminaries . . . lamps, not gods . . . and the earth is not supported by any giant animals—it hangs on *nothing* (Job 26:7).

Isn’t that ridiculous and contrary to science? How can something like the earth “hang on nothing”?

The Bible isn’t a science textbook and shouldn’t be used as one, but I’d not be quick to conclude contradictions with science or to dismiss the writings on scientific grounds, especially considering that science is always changing while the Bible doesn’t change.

Answer (score 0):

**Genesis 8:22**

> "While the earth remains, seedtime and harvest, cold and heat, summer and winter, day and night, shall not cease." ESV

As long as the earth remains its seasons and times remain constant. Their regularity show that God has purpose, i.e. is not randon in His dealings with men.

The seasons, day and night occur regularly and regularity means stability.
Stability means repeating patterns which we can identify and associate with labels e.g. "day", "night".

It is from this stability that. as long as it remains, it cannot be moved.

[Storms and earthquakes{Matt 24:7} may appear to make the earth's stability[pillars]  tremble and shake, but the big picture is that its spinning and orbiting continue to occur  at regular speeds and stability is maintained. The pillars tremble they don't collapse].